# How to install JMapViewer

Tags: java, jmapviewer

I am having an issue using `JMapViewer`.

```
import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.TileLoader;
                                                  ^ Demo.java:20: error: 
package org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces does not exist
```

How can I get rid of that error and use jmapviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have following structure

```
.
|-- Simple.java
`-- jar
    `-- JMapViewer.jar
```

and `Simple.java` looks like this

```
import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.TileLoader;

public class Simple {}
```

all you have to do, is to point to `JMapViewer.jar` while compiling the code

```
> javac -cp jar/JMapViewer.jar Simple.java
```

if you don't you will get an error

```
> javac Simple.java
Simple.java:1: error: package org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces does not exist
import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.TileLoader;
```